# Will Mist support just Trezor or any FIDO/U2F hardware secure key?

Tags: mist, trezor

Trezor recently announced support for Ethereum specifically, as well as being able to act as a standard [FIDO/U2F Security Key](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_2nd_Factor) in the following [Reddit Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/TREZOR/comments/50h8r9/new_trezor_firmware_fidou2f_and_initial_ethereum/).

It's also been discussed that Mist will integrate the Trezor into the Wallet. Can we expect this to be a specific integration of Trezor or will any U2F device be compatible with Mist?

Will Trezor be used for anything in Mist that is beyond what any other standard Security Key can do?